How to use google reviews api?
I'm trying to display Google reviews on my website and I confess I'm totally lost. Maybe because I'm french (don't know) but Google Tutorials seem to me a big mess...
Well I've been there:
https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/review-data
They ask to use "accounts.locations.reviews.list" API to get reviews.
In the API library, there is nothing looking like this api.
Also when I try this url
https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/{accountId}/locations/{$locationId}/reviews
I just have one id (I got in the Business Profile that I manage) and I'm not even sure which one it is and where to find the other one.
I have the following error: CREDENTIALS_MISSING
The step by step tutorial by google don't seem complete...
Anyone could help me please ?
Thanks very much !
